# Determinant of a Vandermonde Matrix with 1 row replaced

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1&1 &...& 1\\1 & 2 & 4& ...& 2^n \\ 1 & 3 & 9 & ... & 3^n\\\vdots\\1 & n & n^2 & ... & n^n\end{bmatrix}$$ the determinant is the superfactorial of $n$ and can be given as $D_n = D_{n-1}(n-1)!$.

However, I need to calculate the determinant of a matrix defined by switching one of the row's with variables like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1&1 &...& 1\\1 & 2 & 4& ...& 2^n \\ b_0 & b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n\\\vdots\\1 & n & n^2 & ... & n^n\end{bmatrix}$$

So given the $b_i$, the "swapped" row and $n$ how can I find the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: Also, I am interested in the behaviour of the determinant given $b_i$ for large $n$ (as $n$ tends to infinity) so please comment if you have an asymptotic formula for the determinant.

Comment: Try row expansion by Row 3. All cofactors are Vandermonde

Comment: If I row expansion around say $b_1$ then I am missing the $1,2,4,5...n$ so the matrix I get is not Vandermonde. What do I do?

Comment: Use Cramer's rule

Comment: As far as I know, Cramer's rule is used for finding solutions to linear equations, in fact, this matrix is one I obtained from applying Kramer's rule to a system I wanted to solve. How do I apply it here?

Comment: @mtheorylord Ah, I thought it might be easier to compute the answer as a solution to a system of equations than it would be to compute it as a determinant.  It seems as though from your perspective, that's going backwards.

Comment: Yup, that's my problem.

Comment: You can use the [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), because your matrix is a rank-1 update of the Vandermonde matrix. The required inverse of the Vandemonde matrix can be found here [Inverse of Vandermonde's Matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix)